# Get XML page from path name

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, parsing, hyperlink

I am working on a site server side that has uses XML to get data. The path to the XML I need is something like "/image/user/username/"

I need to get the XML file from that resulting link using something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

imagesByUser('/../image/user/{{ user.username }}/')
```

I know that the link is working because I tested it seperately and when I clicked on it, it took me to the correct page with the XML data. However, when I try to parse the data I get an xmlHttp.responseXML is null error
on this line

```
var images= xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("image");
```

I get the file with this

```
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
```

xmlHttp.send();

Also, it works when I use a direct file like 
    imagesByUser('images.xml')

So why wont it work from a page off the server??

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question from bottom - I got stuck at `So why wont it work from a page off the server??`

You must specify the correct protocol for AJAX to work. For pages on a hosted server, it must be `http://` and for files on the local file system, it must be `file:///path/filename`.

As far as I know, to work properly with XMLHttpRequest object, you must use the protocol correctly
see example at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)